# AWS CDK accessing a resource in a parent stack from a nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to pass an Arn for a resource created in a parent stack to be used in a nested stack. The aws-cdk documentation states that:

> When a resource from a parent stack is referenced by a nested stack, a CloudFormation parameter will automatically be added to the nested stack and assigned from the parent

However, trying to reference a resource created in a parent stack results in `Circular dependency between resources:` error.

What would be the best way to pass a reference for a resource from a parent stack to a nested one?

```
object TestTemplateApp extends App {


  class MainStack(parent: Construct)
    extends Stack(parent, "Main") {

    //some other resources
    val firstNestedStack = new FirstNestedStack(this)

  }


  class FirstNestedStack(parent: Construct)
    extends NestedStack(parent, "Batch") {


    //some other resources

    val s3Bucket = Bucket.Builder
      .create(this, "id")
      .bucketName(("example"))
      .build()

    val BucketArn = s3Bucket.getBucketArn

    val secondNested = new SecondNestedStack(this, BucketArn)
  }

  class SecondNestedStack(parent: Construct, bucketArn: String) extends NestedStack(parent, "second") {

    //some other resources

    val secondS3Bucket = Bucket.Builder
      .create(this, s" S3WorkspaceBucket")
      .bucketName(s"$bucketArn example") // assume we want to use the ARN of the s3 bucket from the parent in the bucket in the nested stack
      .build()
  }

  val cdkApp = CDKApp.Builder.create().outdir("/tmp/test_template").build()
  val mainStack = new MainStack(cdkApp)
  cdkApp.synth()

}
```

Comment: You are using cdk right? Can you show a minimal code example on what you  are doing? How are you referencing a resource in the parent stack?

Comment: hey! yes I  am using cdk, please have a look over the snippet of code that more less summarizes the structure of my project.

Comment: I cannot see the circular dependency in the code you posted. Maybe it is somewhere else in your resources, can you commenting out resources until it builds?